# NGINX создание виртуальных динамических поддоменов

Tags: nginx

Собственно вопрос:
Имеется сайт "site.ru" работает на NGINX+PHP-FPM без Apache.
Нужно чтобы переходя по ссылкам поддоменов, например:

```
subdomen01.site.ru
subdomen02.site.ru
subdomen03.site.ru
```

по факту оставаться на этом же домене, но адрес чтобы был поддомена. И естественно, чтобы на адреса других каких-нибудь поддоменов это не срабатывало.
Ещё, поддомены физически не существуют.

Comment: В server_name можно регулярки писать https://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: Поддомены (или wildcard) надо завести в DNS. В nginx в server_name указать `server_name .site.ru;`. http://nginx.org/ru/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#server_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Указываете списком все имена сервера, через пробел. Дополнительно переопределяете константу SERVER_NAME, чтобы в php верно было проинициализировано значение `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.ru subdomen01.site.ru subdomen02.site.ru subdomen03.site.ru;

    ...


    location ~ \.php$ {

        ...

        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_param;
        fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME $http_host;
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вроде завелось как надо! Позже отпишу по результатам всех проверок!!!